# How to draw diagrams of Path, velocity and time for a complex problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, string

What does an approach or a solution strategy look like for the following problem: Two point-shaped bodies with the masses m_1=100g and m_2=200g are connected to a string of 30 cm length and lie on a very smooth table of height 80 cm. Body 1 is located at the edge of the table and is very easily nudged at the time tleny 0 s.
Draw the a (t), v (t) and s (t) charts by the time of impact!

I am thankful for every help.

Here is my drawing:

[image]

Comment: Show your efforts. What do you think?

Comment: Hi, Lampert12, welcome! Please consider that people are more likely to put the effort in writing good answers when you've shown some effort in writing your question as well. I've included your picture (don't post links, embed pictures and anything else relevant in the post itself), that you had posted as an answer and I've turned it the right side too.

Answer (score 1):

In general, making a sketch of the geometry with all the involved forces is almost always useful (it would also help here for me to even understand the positions of the masses). From there, figure out the dynamics at that instant. Or, if you can, the dynamics for all times. Otherwise, draw another sketch some small time later, and figure out the dynamics from there.

For the diagrams it is often useful to start with the accelation, as it tends to have the least complex structure (there are of course exceptions). Once you have a formula for the acceleration, just integrate to get $v(t)$, and integrate again for $s(t)$.

If the goal is to just sketch the diagrams without any formulas, you can remember that going from $a(t) \rightarrow v(t) \rightarrow s(t)$, constants turn to straight lines with a slope of that constant, straight lines turn to parabolas, and from there the curves just turn into steeper and steeper curves with more curvature ($x^3, x^4, \ldots$).